# how to get yaw from quaternion values?

Tags: ros, rosaria, yaw, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am new to ROS and this community. I am working with pioneer 3dx robot. My aim is to drive it in a square shape path and return back to its initial position. I am able to get quaternion values [x,y,z,w] from my robot. But for the purpose of turning the robot 90 degree I think I need rotation about z axis [yaw]. I have written  the following code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h" 
#include <ros/console.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>

double quatx;
double quaty;
double quatz;
double quatw;


void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "Test_FK"); // connect to roscore
    ros::NodeHandle n;                                     // node object
    ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000, ComPoseCallback);
    ros::spin();
}


void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)            
{
    ROS_INFO("Seq: [%d]", msg->header.seq);
    ROS_INFO("Position-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.position.x,msg->pose.pose.position.y, msg->pose.pose.position.z);
    ROS_INFO("Orientation-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f], w: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.orientation.x, msg->pose.pose.orientation.y, msg->pose.pose.orientation.z, msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    
   float linearposx=msg->pose.pose.position.x;
   float linearposy=msg->pose.pose.position.y;
   double quatx= msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;
   double quaty= msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;
   double quatz= msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;
   double quatw= msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;
   
    tf::Quaternion q(quatx, quaty, quatz, quatw);
    tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
    
    ROS_INFO("Roll: [%f],Pitch: [%f],Yaw: [%f]",roll,pitch,yaw);
    return ;
}
```

**I code compiles and do return some values. I was just spinning the robot in anti clockwise direction. Here are the values**:

Position-> x: [0.000000], y: [-0.001000], z: [0.000000]
Orientation-> x: [0.000000], y: [0.000000], z: [-0.054026], w: [0.998540]
Roll: [0.000000],Pitch: [0.000000],Yaw: [-0.10810]

Position-> x: [0.000000], y: [-0.001000], z: [0.000000]
Orientation-> x: [0.000000], y: [0.000000], z: [-0.055554], w: [0.998456]
Roll: [0.000000],Pitch: [0.000000],Yaw: [-0.111165]

Position-> x: [0.000000], y: [-0.001000], z: [0.000000]
Orientation-> x: [0.000000], y: [0.000000], z: [-0.055554], w: [0.998456]
Roll: [0.000000],Pitch: [0.000000],Yaw: [-0.111165]

**I don't understand  whether i am getting the correct values or not. To my understanding Yaw is in radians and must increase with time [spinning at one posiiton].**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238083/how-to-get-yaw-from-quaternion-values?/) by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2016-06-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/30649/vsd/) on 2017-06-28**:
Hi Tomm I would like to ask how were u able to achieve it using Navigation and actionlib. I am working on a similar project and am stuck and have less time, so i can't read from scratch. If you can walk me through the steps and probably share your code, it would be great help Thanks

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-31**:
@vsd, you should ask a new question to get some help with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Spinning counter clockwise yaw should increase, yes, to convert check [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/41233/how-to-understand-robot-orientation-from-quaternion-yaw-angle/).

If you want to move in a square you can easily use the [Navigation & ActionLib](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) to move your robot to e.g. (1,0), (1,-1), (0,1), (0, 0). It will then rotate automatically.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on 2016-06-27**:
Navigation & ActionLib is an easier way to do it. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [vsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/30649/vsd/) on 2017-06-27**:
Hi Tomm
I would like to ask how were u able to achieve it using Navigation and actionlib.
I am working on a similar project and am stuck and have less time, so i can't read from scratch.
If you can walk me through the steps and probably share your code, it would be great help
Thanks